# PDO or MSSQL_connect - in PHP 5.3

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I am working on a website that runs by MYSQL and Linux Php 5.3 - and i need to work with this as well as a remote MSSQL database.

I read that PDO this is the way to connect to MSSQL.
It though seems there are both a PDO and a more familiar mssql_connect solution.
I have little to no experience with either PDO or mssql_connect.

On the PHP documentation i find:

Mssql_connect - The familiar expression:

```
 <?php
 // Create a link to MSSQL
 $link = mssql_connect('KALLESPC\SQLEXPRESS', 'sa', 'phpfi');

 // Select the database 'php'
 mssql_select_db('php', $link);
 ?>
```

PDO - Which i haven't tried before - which needs a driver !(?) :

```
 <?php
 /* Connect to an ODBC database using driver invocation */
 $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
 $user = 'dbuser';
 $password = 'dbpass';

 try {
 $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
 } catch (PDOException $e) {
 echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
 }
 ?>
```

So what to choose and why ?

Comment: I'd go with PDO as mysql_* functions are deprecated http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php

Comment: Hi Mike.. This is a MSSQL and where MYSQL will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5 - I don't read the same for MS SQL ?

Comment: Misread that - sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not tried it yet.  So I can't say for sure if it works or not.
PHP Manual says use pdo::dblib http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Microsoft does have it's own set of drivers but you have to be on a windows machine to use them. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL connection with PDO:

```
$db_handle = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=$server; Database=$database", $user, $pass);
```

MySQL connection with PDO:

```
$db_handle = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database", $user, $pass);
```

I don't see what your confusion is?